# gradle test task failing on Test Util class extending TestCase but having no test method

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I have a legacy test class using old Junit 3 way:

```
public class MyTestUtil extends TestCase {
  //class has helper methods but no method starting with "test"
}
```

I have other test classes which extends this class:

```
public class MyTests extends MyTestUtil {
       public void testSomething() {
       }
}
```

I am trying to run this using gradle build file. And the build fails complaining with a warning:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in myPackage.MyTestUtil
```

The build obviously runs fine when I exclude this class from test task:

```
test {
  exclude '**/MyTestUtil.class'   
}
```

But I don't know if excluding like this is the only solution.

Is there a way to do away with this warning?

Comment: just add a test method. without test methods in it, that class has no reason to exist anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the JUnit [FAQ](https://junit.org/junit4/faq.html#running_11):

> Why do I get the warning "AssertionFailedError: No tests found in XXX" when I run my test?
>
> Make sure you have more or more method annotated with `@Test`.

Either add at least one test or exclude the class like you described.